# как правильно работать с сокетами php

Tags: php, сокет

Вот взял из офф. [**мануала**](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-socket-client.php) две функции запустил на локальном серваке, браузер тупо бесконечно грузится. Я новичек в этом деле поэтому поясните как правильно настроить для роботы с сокетами. Задача разобраться, что-бы можно было отправлять хотя-бы элементарные сообщение от сервера к клиенту.

```
 /// сервер
 $socket = stream_socket_server('tcp://socket:8000', $errno, $errstr);

 if(!$socket) {
       echo "$errno - $errstr </br> \n";
  }else{

   while($conn = stream_socket_accept($socket)) {
       fwrite($conn, 'Локальное время ' . date('n/j/Y g:i a') . "\n");
       fclose($conn);
    }
   fclose($socket);
  }


   /* -------------------------- */
   /// клиент

   $fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://socket:8000", $errno, $errstr, 30);
   if (!$fp) {
      echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    } else {
    fwrite($fp, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.socket\r\nAccept:
    */*\r\n\r\n");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 1024);
     }
    fclose($fp);
   }
```

Comment: Какому именно клиенту вы пытаетесь отправить данные?

В целом, все стандартно как и везде, открываем сокет, посылаем данные, ждем ответ если нужно, закрываем сокет.

Comment: У вас и сервер и клиент на PHP. Браузер при таком подходе не берет участия при взаимодействии. Для двусторонней передачи данных необходимо из консоли сначала запустить скрипт сервера, а после этого клиента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Пример использования сокетов: Простой TCP/IP сервер](http://php.net/manual/ru/sockets.examples.php)

Comment: Ответ-ссылка. Пишите развернутые ответы.